# How does DROPBOX response (JSON) data look like?

Tags: json, dropbox

Good day, does anyone know typical JSON response data, when accessing a file? I am more interested in whether or not one can check if a response object is a file or a directory!

Thanx mates

Comment: see https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common JSON answer, when you try to get information about file/folder.
You can see more information about request [here](http://dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata)
if is_dir is true, it's a folder.

> {
>
> ```
> "size": "225.4KB",
> "rev": "35e97029684fe",
> "thumb_exists": false,
> "bytes": 230783,
> "modified": "Tue, 19 Jul 2011 21:55:38 +0000",
> "client_mtime": "Mon, 18 Jul 2011 18:04:35 +0000",
> "path": "/Getting_Started.pdf",
> "is_dir": false,
> "icon": "page_white_acrobat",
> "root": "dropbox",
> "mime_type": "application/pdf",
> "revision": 220823
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Thanks buddy, project up and running. Keep it fresh.